# QT C++ function with optional parameter for strings

Tags: c++, qt, tostring

I'm having problem with the writing a toString function on QT C++.

For example, I have this in my header file QString toString(QString delimiter = " : "); and I get the following error

error: default argument for parameter of type 'QString' has type 'const char [3]'

The otpional parameters worked fine for other types, but it seems that the compiler interprets " : " as type char and as such gives me the following error (i thought chars use ' ', turns out i was wrong).

I googled this stuff, but couldn't find anything useless, i'm pretty there must be an easy fix to it, but I'm new to the language.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

<del>The compiler error is saying that the paramater is of type `QString` but the default value you've given is of type `const char[3]` (a const character array) because it is a string literal. `QString` does have a constructor that takes a `const char*` (and remember arrays decay to pointers) so normally it would be able to perform an implicit conversion to from `const char*` to `QString` however it seems that constructor has been declared `explicit` and so it must be called explicitly.</del>

Edit: It's not explicit, the header just needs to be included :)

Comment: yeah, I tried casting it like that, but it didn't work, this was the error :  invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QString'

Comment: aaah, my stupid head, what was missing is the #include<QString>, now it works, thank you very much :)

Comment: Well yeah, the action takes place in the header file for now :)